# How To Use A List Instead Of Multiple Variables In Python

Tags: python, list, variables

As a problem i have to store a 'race distance' for about 6 different 'cars' how would i do this in a list rather than using at least 6 different variables

I have tried using variables however the solution needs to be more 'effeicent'.

Comment: `distances = [distance_1, distance_2...distance_6]`?

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python list tutorial", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use a dictionary instead of a list so you can associate "race distance" for each type of car. This way you'd have everything in the same variable instead of dealing with 6 variables. it could give you something like:

```
myCarsAndDistances = {
     'car1' : '200000',
     'car2'   : '70000',
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Lists of things

To store items in a name, or your races, use a python [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), or [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

Which is easily declared as `[value1, value2]`

As for the items in the lists, or a single race. You can use one of the following:

## A [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

```py
races = [('race1', 50), ('race2', 100)]
```

You can then access the races:

```py
for race in races:
    name, dist = race
    print(name, dist)
```

## A [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

```py
races [{'name': 'race1', 'distance': 50}, {'name': 'race2', 'distance': 100}]
```

Access the races as such:

```py
for race in races:
    print(race[name], race[dist])
```

or, more usually:

```py
races = {'race1': 50, 'race2': 100}
```

To lookup a specific race:

```py
print(races['race1'])
```

Or loop all the races:

```py
for name, distance in races.items():
    print(name, distance)
```

## A [class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

```py
class Race:
    def __init__(self, name, distance):
        self.name = name
        self.distance = distance

races = [Race('race1', 50), Race('race2', 100)]
```

Again, for access:

```py
for race in races:
    print(race.name, race.distance)
```

I might have forgotten some other ways, but I guess it answers your question.